# Swift: extend protocol whose associated type is an array

Tags: arrays, swift, protocol-extension

I am trying to create an Rx operator that works on arrays. I've tried this simple extension:

```
extension ObservableType where Element == Array<Any> {
    func beat<U>(_ beat: Observable<U>) -> Observable<Element.Element> {
        let lhs = self.flatMap { Observable.from($0) }
        return Observable.zip(lhs, beat).map { $0.0 }
    }
}
```

Now, I've noted `Array<Any>` because the otherwise I get 
`Reference to generic type 'Array' requires arguments in <...>`, but this way the return value is of courses `Observable<Any>`.

Is it even possible to return an observable with the actual `Element` of the array?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```swift
    func beat<U>(_ beat: Observable<[U]>) -> Observable<[U]> where [U] == Element {
        Observable.zip(self, beat).map { $0.0 }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you want to use the [parametrized extensions](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#parameterized-extensions) that is not implemented in Swift 5.2.

As a workaround, you can create a global generic function that accepts `Array<T>` as the second parameter.